# Unable to store LineStrings and Polygons - MEAN + Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm facing an issue that I was not able to solve looking at other Q/As on SO.

I'm building a web application that uses **Google Maps Api** as an interface to a **MEAN Stack Application**. I'm also using **Mongoose** to create my **MongoDB Schema**.

> Unluckily, I'm not able to store **LineStrings** and **Polygons**. I'm only able to store **Points** and query them as I want (e.g. find closest points to another one).

When I try to **POST** a **LineString** or a **Polygon** I get the following error:

```
geoObjects validation failed
Cast to Array failed for value \"coordinates\" at path \"coordinates\"
```

[Here's a Gist with the full Postman Log](https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/2f21274010423dffdff57bd657896038).

Here's my **Schema**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var geoObjects = new Schema({
                                    name : {type: String},
                                    type: {
                                              type: String,
                                              enum: [
                                                        "Point",
                                                        "LineString",
                                                        "Polygon"
                                                    ],
                                                  default : 'Point'
                                           },
                                    coordinates: [Number],
});

geoObjects.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('geoObjects', geoObjects);
```

This is my **Post Route**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var GeoObjects = require('./model.js');    

app.post('/geoObjects', function(req, res) {

        // Creates a new Point based on the Mongoose schema and the post body
        var newObj = new GeoObjects(req.body);

        // New Points is saved in the db.
        newObj.save(function(err) {
          if (err){
            res.send(err);
            return;
          }

            // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new point
            res.json(req.body);
        });
    });
```

And these are two examples of **LineString** and **Polygons** that I'm trying to POST:

```
{
  "name":"myPolygon",
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
                  [ [25.774, -80.190], [18.466, -66.118], 
                    [32.321, -64.757], [25.774, -80.190] 
                  ]
                 ]
}

{ 
  "name":"myLineString",    
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates":  [ 
                   [17.811, 12.634], [12.039, 18.962], 
                   [15.039, 18.962], [27.039, 18.962]
                  ]
}
```

> In a previous version, I had `coordinates: [Schema.Types.Mixed]` that
>   allowed me to store all the 3 kind of geoObjects, but, unluckily, I
>   was forced to switch to a different schema since with
>   `Schema.Types.Mixed` it was not possible to let my queries work on
>   points.

1. **Why Am I not able to POST LineStrings and Polygons?**
2. **How Can I solve this issue?**

Thanks in advance, if you need any clarification on the problem just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue splitting the initial schema in 3 different schemas, one per each type.

Here are correct schemas which allow using `geoQueries` and storing `geoObjects`

**marker-model.js**

```
// Pulls Mongoose dependency for creating schemas
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var markers = new Schema({
    name : {type: String},
    type: {
        type: String,
        default : 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {type: [Number], index:true},
    created_at:  {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at:  {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
markers.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

// Indexes this schema in 2dsphere format 
markers.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('markers', markers);
```

**linestring-model.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a LineString Schema.
var linestrings = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    geo : {
        type : {type: String,
            default: "LineString"},
        coordinates : Array
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
linestrings.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

linestrings.index({geo : '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('linestrings', linestrings);
```

**polygon-model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// Creates a Polygon Schema.
var polygons = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required : true},
    geo : {
        type : {type: String,
            default: "Polygon"},
        coordinates : Array
    },
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

// Sets the created_at parameter equal to the current time
polygons.pre('save', function(next){
    now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if(!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now
    }
    next();
});

polygons.index({geo : '2dsphere'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('polygons', polygons);
```

**LineString Insert**:

```
{  
    "name" : "myLinestring", 
    "geo" : {
        "type" : "LineString", 
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                17.811, 
                12.634
            ], 
            [
                12.039, 
                18.962
            ], 
            [
                15.039, 
                18.962
            ], 
            [
                29.039, 
                18.962
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**Polygon Insert:**

```
{  
    "name" : "Poly", 
    "geo" : {
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" :  [
                           [ 
                             [25.774, -80.190], [18.466, -66.118], 
                             [32.321, -64.757], [25.774, -80.190] 
                           ]
                         ]
    }
}
```

I hope it will help someone.